# Jquery error. "Unsupported pseudo: mcsInView" while using malihu scroll plugin

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using one of the most popular jquery custom scroll plugin: [Malihu](http://manos.malihu.gr/)

It has an option, that helps to determine if element is in scrollable parents container viewport (lool at [Plugin-specific jQuery expression](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)). On plugin's [demo page](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/code-examples/custom-jquery-expressions/mcsinview/) it works more than fine, but not in my own project. And i can't find the answer anywhere.

When i try using this option in my project, i always get an error:
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: mcsInView"

Jquery: V 3.3.1
Malihu: V 3.1.5

Jquery code example:

```
$('.route_wrapper .info')
    .mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons: {
            enable: false
        },
        scrollInertia: 0,
        callbacks:{
            onScroll:function(){
                if ($('#vid3').is(':mcsInView')) {
                    console.log('In viewport')
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `':mcsInView'` doesn't look like a valid selector. `.is()` 1rst and only parameter is supposed to be a valid selector.

Comment: Sure, but i don't know exactly what ':mcsInView' refers to.

Comment: If it is not difficult to u: look on line 2421 of plugin's js file. There is a function that extends jQuery expressions. One of this is mcsInView.

Comment: Okey, I will have a look. By the way I wonder why you put this in your code without knowing what it refers to :|

Comment: Thank you so much. I rely on an example. I did not write this plugin. There is documentation I adhere to.

Comment: It seems the plugin isn't compatible with jQuery 3.x branch.  Someone ran into [this same issue](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/comment-page-60/#comment-19123) three years ago but the plugin author did not give a fix neither a quick fix.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I watched all this information:(

Comment: And in the end, I tend to write my own solution to this problem...

Comment: Look forward for other libraries like [Simple bar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar). I'm sure you will find an alternative.

Comment: Thank u, friend. I'll have a look.